# PHPunit mock returns always null

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I am mocking a class to test its methods however i can't set the required return value. 
Here is what i have done

```
 <?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Lopo\Payment;

class PaymentTest extends TestCase
{
    public $stub;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->stub = $this->createMock(Payment::class);
    }

    public function testProceedPaymentMethod()
    {
        $this->stub->expects($this->any())->method('proceed')
        ->will($this->returnValue('fooo'));

        var_dump($this->stub->proceed(10)); // not returning fooo 

    }
}
```

I tried without setup method
I tried with `createMock`, `getMockBuilder()` but always getting `NULL` instead of the specefied return value.

how can i solve this ?

Comment: Can you post the code of the mocked class?

Comment: What version of phpunit are you using? I can't replicate this - the code you've posted looks fine to me (albeit slightly more complicated that it needs to be - see Sebastian's answer).

Comment: I am using version 7

Comment: Check If the method is declared as private

Answer (score 0):

You want `$this->stub->method('proceed')->willReturn('foo');`.

Comment: I tried that as well  but `var_dump($this->stub->proceed(10));` still returning `NULL` ? I am not sure what I am missing ?

Comment: I'm currently having this aect same issue with PHPUnit 7.5.20